# Does an object with a higher pull of gravity influence a weaker gravity field exerted by another object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

[image: Sorry for the quality of the drawing, but I just made it quickly in Paint.]For a simple example, let's just take a big basketball-sized iron ball as the object with a very strong pull of gravity (let's say that it has a volume of 200cm^3, and mass of 100 kilograms. Take also into account that it is also at rest) in an **empty** universe, where just space and time exist.

Let's suddenly make a tiny styrofoam ball appear in that empty universe out of nothing, in contact *and* (at rest) to the iron ball (let's say it has a volume of 5cm^3 and a mass of 1 gram).

After that, think that we are perfectly able to go to that universe and be next to the pair of balls (without interacting at all with them because of our gravity) and move so that we are absolutely still with our **"gravity-pull measuring machine"** making the *gravity-pull measuring machine's* detector's field of view *"look at them"* and *see* sort of two-dimensional circles, the iron ball, and the styrofoam ball right at the center. It is exactly 50 cm away in a straight line from the nucleus of the iron ball, and 20cm from the nucleus of the styrofoam ball.

***My question is:*** **would it be able to detect that there is another object apart from the iron ball in there, or would it feel everything as a unique gravity field?**

**Another question that I would like to include here** (please do not take it as part of the main question, if you are not interested in answering it just ignore it): **is there any mathematical formula to allow us to work out the physical properties of an Object** '*A* **(mass and volume, at least for that *both* objects are spherical) having the distance from the nucleus of an Object** '*B*', **mass and dimensions of** *B ("Mathematically comparing" how a gravitational field in a spherical body would look like with the one that has been "observed")?*

Any help at all would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the quality of the drawing, I just made it quickly in Paint

Comment: The drawing shows two-dimensional circles, but they're supposed to be spheres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the concept of a "gravitational field" has slightly misled you here.

All objects with a mass excert a gravitational force on each other.*

So the iron ball excerts a force on the styrofoam ball and vice versa. Both of them excert a force on your detector (or else it wouldn't be able to measure gravitation) and your detector excerts a force on both balls.

In many cases we can "reduce" this "everything attracts everything"-picture to a much easier one, like the gravitational field of the earth. The error we make here because we do not care about our detector, humans, other living beeings or every single atom is usually small. Small enough to not notice a big difference, especially if we are far away. We can safely assume that the position of the butter in my refridgerater does not influence the orbit of jupiter in a measurable amount.

The problem is: it does! Ok, admitted, by moving it into the refridgerator i did not move the center of mass of the earth (including my butter), so earth moved a bit in the other direction. But taking your picture, there is a difference between a iron ball and a iron ball + a styrofoam ball. It's the difference between 100kg and 100.001 kg. The center of mass also moved a (tiny) bit, but it moved.

So yes, a detector, sensitive enough, would detect it. But from a distance it could not detect the difference between your two balls and a single ball with mass 100.001 kg with its center at the center of mass of your two balls.

<sub>* speaking about non-relativistic, non-quantum-mechanical, macroscopic objects here, there might exist other cases i'm not aware of currently.</sub>

Comment: I commented in my question about thinking that the detector wouldn't interact gravitationally with any of the balls.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine anything about the source of a gravitational field from only one measurement. You need to map the gravitational field around the object. If you were to map the gravitational field with any amount of accuracy, you would be able to tell what the mass distribution of the object is. The gravitational field at a point is given by $\mathbf g(\mathbf r)=\int dV' \frac{G\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf{r'}|^2}$. Given enough points $\mathbf r$, it should be possible to calculate $\rho(\mathbf{r'})$.